# HTTP server sending email

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm developing server using Go with net/http, and I want to send email using net/smtp.

If I call SendEmail in api function, email was not sent but api response shows well

```
func main() {
    ...
    http.ListenAndServe("port", router) //In main func last line
}

//This is api function
func UpdatePassword(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
    SendEmail()
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(SomeData) //response
}
```

With this code api response shows well but there no printed Failed or Succeed message that i can see

And SendEmail function

```
func SendMail() {
    from := "my gmail"
    pass := "pwd"
    to := "email"

    msg := ...

    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Failed")
        return
    }

    fmt.Print("Succeed")
}
```

Testing on other project, SendEmail function works well.

I thought use SendEmail function with goroutine can solve this problem but it was not.

Comment: What is "does not work"? Error message? Panic? What is the implementation of `SendEmail()`? Try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: @Yadu Yes I tested UpdatePassword function by using postman

Comment: "no printed Failed or Succeed message that i can see" --- how/where do you check it?

Comment: @zerkms I check them in Terminal (GOLand). I could see Succeed message when i tested SendMail function without http.ListenAndServe.

Comment: If you don't see it in the stdout (but you can see other `fmt.Print`)- then it presumably was not run. Add another `fmt.Print` right before `SendMail` call, and another as a first line of `SendMail`. Alternatively - learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @zerkms Thank your help and kindness. I solved problem. I just Invalidate caches / Restart.. I think reflex cause problem some times.